# Meteor remove not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am building an app using Meteor and am trying to write a function to remove an item from a cart. I have a collection called `Cart`. In my cart.js file I have:

```
Cart.allow({
   remove: function(userId, doc) {
   return true;
 }
});
```

In my Cart collection I also have a click event to remove an item from the cart:

```
'click .removeItem': function(e, tmpl) {
   alert('clicked remove item button');
   Cart.remove({_id: this._id});
  }
});
```

However, I get two errors in the console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Cart is not defined

and

remove failed: Access denied

Can someone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I moved the allow method into my collections.js file and it worked!

Comment: That was a right thing, make sure you give the permissions like `insert`, `update`, `remove` in the `collections.js` file.